# Adding prefix and suffix to a content type field

Tags: entities, nodes

Is there a way to add content to a content type's field in a mechanized way? Say for instance I have a field for how many servings a recipe is going to make but I don't want my user to have to write "Makes" and "Servings." over and over again and risk spelling something wrong.

Is there a way to make it so all she needs is a number field and I can automagically make it say "Makes" [number] "servings."

Perhaps there is a hook or module that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add prefix and suffix in the display settings of the field with the [Simple Field Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter) module

1. Download and enable the module
2. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/mycontenttype/display
3. Click on the settings icon for the specific field

Comment: please see my updated answer, forgot to include module

Comment: This module works only with text fields